# Shifting bits, where did it came from?

Tags: java, bit

```
int a=0xFFFF; 
        System.out.println("test1 "+Integer.toBinaryString(a)); 
        a<<=1;
        System.out.println("test2 "+Integer.toBinaryString(a));
```

> ```
> Output:
> test1 1111111111111111
> test2 11111111111111110
> ```

My question is, where did the `0` came from?

Comment: It came from `a<<=1;`

Comment: Are you asking if the '0' bit comes from some particular register or variable or whatever, such that it might sometimes be '0' or sometimes '1'?

Comment: Ofc., it came from the shifting, but I'm wondering how.

Comment: 0x1FFFE also equals test2

Comment: `int` is a data type represented with 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no leading zeroes in the returned `String` from `Integer.toBinaryString`.  There are 16 `1`s in `0xFFFF`, but there are 16 `0`s too.

```
00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111  // 16 printed
```

Then the left shift by 1 made a zero significant.

```
00000000 00000001 11111111 11111110  // 17 printed
```

- [`Integer.toBinaryString` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in binary (base 2) **with no extra leading 0s**.

Comment: Why are there 16 0's if a hex number is made of 16 digits?

Comment: An `int` is 4 bytes, which is equivalent to 32 bits, which is equivalent to 8 hexadecimal characters (4 bits per hexadecimal character).  You could have said `int a = 0x0000FFFF;`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert it into binary, but to show me all the 0's?

Comment: You can always subtract the length of the string from 32, and print that many 0s.

Comment: Thought there was other way than concatenating.